# Centos 6.4 network manager disappeared

Tags: centos-6, networkmanager

4 Desktop and from today the newtrok manager stopped appearing and only appears if I run the following command "nm-applet" and keep the terminal window open in order for me to connect to internet via wi-fi,

I want to get back to the default behavior and want to have the network manager start at boot up time and remain alive without me having to have a terminal window opne , can you please let me know what caused this change in behavior and how I can get the default behavior back.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
chkconfig NetworkManager on
```

From [here](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Laptops/NetworkManager).
If you still want to start it manually, you could use

```
nm-applet &
```

You could also edit `~/.xinitrc` (if it isn't there, create it with `#!/bin/bash` at the top), and add

```
nm-applet &
```

`.xinitrc` is run when the x server turns on, which should be about the right time for the applet to run. You could also try `rc.local` possibly, if the applet does not need X.

Comment: I already tried chkconfig NetworkManager on , it does not help , and I do not want to start it manually , I want to avoid doing that.

Comment: @user1965449 You could add it to `rc.local`, so it would run when the x server starts.